# Is there kafka push plugin available for web analytic matomo v3.13

Tags: apache-kafka, matomo

Kafka plugin for matomo analytics not working ,how to get stream data to kafka from matomo

Comment: Hi! I'm looking for the same solution. Did you found any clues?

Comment: i did not get exact solution however there is a link without any concrete info https://plugins.matomo.org/KafkaPush?matomoversion=2